# Light wave with gravitational component

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

It may sound a little naive but... Is it possible for a light wave to have a gravitational wave component?

Comment: Can one construct graviphotons, i.e. photons that couple strongly to a gravitational wave of identical wavelength? Probably. I don't see why not... now, if you can come up with an experimental implementation, I am pretty sure that the Nobel is yours.

Comment: I don't know what a light wave with a gravitational wave component is supposed to be.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Think gravitational vacuum polarization or plasmons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When and if all fundamental forces are unified which happens at very high energies, imagined only for cosmological models, all gauge bosons become massless and transfer a unified "force". In that sense it should be possible that the "light waves" build up by the confluence of the elementary fields of photon, gluon, W and Z and gravitons might ( in some model) carry all four fundamental components with some percentage.  No wonder it is called [primordial soup.](http://www.counterbalance.org/cq-kolb/soup-frame.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly small number of known exact solutions to general relativity.

One of them is the so called [monochromatic electromagnetic plane wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_electromagnetic_plane_wave) where the Stress-Energy of the electromagnetic wave is a source of gravity and there is a gravitational wave and an electromagnetic wave and the gravitational wave and the electromagnetic wave travel together.

It satisfies the Maxwell and the Einstein equations so the fields and the metric coevolve together so that Maxwell, and the metric, tell the electromagnetic field how to evolve and the Stress-Energy tensor of the electromagnetic field, and Einstein, tell the metric field how to evolve. And the things they evolve into are exactly what they are and they evolve together in a consistent fashion.

It's one of a few known electrovacuum solutions to the Einstein-Maxwell system.

Comment: It has one huge flaw, though... you have to get a Death Star (TM) on loan from Darth Vader (TM) to produce the necessary energy density to measure the gravitational correction to the em solution. :-)